# How to see the query FirestoreReactiveRepository in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And the FirestoreReactiveRepository.
I'm created a custom query and I want to see what is the query it builds.
I tried to enable the logs with this config but it didn't work:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```